# Go to Activity from Fragment in Android Error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I've a problem when I want to go to Activity from Fragment. This is my code:

Fragment:

```
public class details extends Fragment {

    private Button btn_video;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);

btn_video = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_video);

        btn_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), video.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Activity: (I've changed this file, you can see below)

```
public class video extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);

        final VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
        video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.prueba));
        video.start();
    }
}
```

I've come to get the video display and reproduce, but the app is closed, by console I see that this Activity is inside the thread. I think the fragment isn't stop and I think this reload. This is exception:

```
11-12 20:15:46.741  18249-18249/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, PID: 18249
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.articulo@4269f860
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1266)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:653)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1226)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:134)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1133)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:378)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1204)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2755)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3414)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Somebody help me with this problem. Or tell me where I'm having mistake.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I edit this comment, if you can find it useful this. Ok, I found a temporary fix. It is this:

I've changed Activity to Fragment.

public class video extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video, container, false);
    constants.setPrincipal(false);

    // When I rotate the screen, I've a problem.
    //getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    VideoView video = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity());
    video.setMediaController(mediaController);
    video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.prueba));
    video.start();

    return rootView;
}
```

}

I say this is temporary fix, because when I rotate the screen for I want to video in fullscreen. The main activity become in landscape, this reload. So, I only can to show the video in portrait. I'm trying search a new fix.

If somebody can help me. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I found the error, it was something else, the activity details you came a bundle from another fragment, this bundle was an arraylist.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new details();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
ArrayList<articulo> seleccionado= new ArrayList<articulo>();
seleccionado.add(((articulo) articulo));
bundle.putSerializable("variables", seleccionado);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).hide(hide)
         .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

To fix it I've used public static variable to store the product data.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new details();

public static ArrayList<articulo> articuloDetails = new ArrayList<articulo>();
articuloDetails.add(((articulo) articulo));

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).hide(hide)
         .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

`getActivity().startActivity(intent);`

instead of

`startActivity(intent);`

Correct me if I'm wrong though but a Fragment is always inside an Activity. That's why it should call the Activity it is in first to be able to start another Activity. This might be due to the fact that an Activity can hold multiple Fragments but a Fragment is not able to hold any Activities.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but it doesn't work me. You're right, forget getActivity() as a "Fragment" is inside of an "Activity". I think the exception that returns is because to get the "Fragment" one bundle is passed. Inside is the video button and I know that the Bundle is not canceling, could this be so?

Comment: I presume that the loading of the Activity goes just fine if you are not using any code of the video player? (Just an empty Activity that is)

Comment: Yes, the Activity works fine with video or without video, but returns the exception, I leave a picture a little more descriptive.[link](https://67c66fb66254f5d6b1c56b9af91d0027ae5ff291.googledrive.com/host/0Bxq_1DLJ8ud3Tjk1T3VaOTBOV3c/screenshot1.png) Thanks.

Comment: I think the bundle is inheriting, am I right? Correct me if I'm wrong, thanks.

Comment: The parcing of the Bundle seems like it is going wrong. But I am not sure why you are not able to rotate and/or load an Activity from a Fragment without receiving the error.
I'll get back to you this Saturday okay, I'll then try to create an example project where I'll load the video in an Activity from a Fragment. (I'll add a GitHub link so you can play around with it from there)

Comment: As promised, here is the example project I created to load a video.

https://github.com/avdkamp/AndroidVideoSample

Comment: Thank you so much @Albert, I'll play with and comment on it.